# MultiTouch TouchPad versus Mouse - which is more powerful?

Tags: touch-screen, efficiency, ease-of-use

There are old questions here from the 2012 era before MultiTouch became popular in both Touch**Screens** and Touch**Pads**.  Users tend to forget that using more than one finger is where the power comes in.  One finger is mouse-like, using two or more fingers opens up many more gestures.  Forgetting about TouchSreens for a moment and focusing on which provides more efficiency and empowers the user more, what wins, the mouse or a multiTouch TouchPad?  Are their studies?

Comment: The criteria in my case are mobile users performing otherwise normal Windows functions.  The context in my case are mobile users demanding a wireless mouse to use their $2700 ThinkPad TabletPC already natively equipped with touchScreen, stylus, touchPad, and trackPoint.  Seems to me a multiTouch TouchPad increases efficiency much more than any mouse.

Comment: Mice vary in their design - so likely some mice are 'better' than others.

Comment: "users demanding a wireless mouse" – What's stopping them from buying one themselves?

Answer (score 1):

What is the criteria to decide more *powerful*? Touchpads with three-finger taps can perform the *same* functions as two-button mice with scroll wheels, which three-button trackballs can emulate. What "wins" is what's available. Desktops rarely have touchpads. Laptops usually don't come with mice. Only the faithful go out of their way to purchase trackballs and touchsticks.